# query prolog with php

Tags: php, prolog

i am trying to make a sudoku game with php, html and prolog, the idea is to use prolog program to slove the sudoku then get the results via PHP, i have write this code down folowing a tutorial online but im getting this error

```
 Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'test' (T_STRING) in C:\wamp\www\Sudoku\index.php on line 13
```

here is my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Soduku</title>
<link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
</head>

<body>
<div id="content">
<?php

$output=exec("\"c:/Program Files (x86)/swipl/bin/swipl-win.exe\"" -f test.pl -g test);
echo"<pre>";
print_r($output);
echo"</pre>";

?>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Have a look at the [description of the `exec` command](http://php.net/manual/en/function.exec.php). Your `$output` isn't what you think it is.

Comment: Also, the switch you want to load a file is `-l` not `-f`. And your program needs to end with a `halt` statement in prolog.

Comment: @TasosPapastylianou Just curious, how did you find the `-l` option? I don't see it in the documentation....

Comment: I just did `man prolog` on linux, but `prolog --help` also provides a summary

Comment: im working on windows

Comment: @TasosPapastylianou Hmm, maybe it is another prolog, swi-prolog at least is never installed as `prolog`.

Comment: no no, swi-prolog it is (on my linux mint anyway)

Comment: @TasosPapastylianou Alright, good to know! Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The -f test.pl -g test is not a string.
Change your code to

```
$output=exec("\"c:/Program Files (x86)/swipl/bin/swipl-win.exe\" -f test.pl -g test");
```

Comment: when i do this the page dont load, it keep only charging infinitly

Comment: no it just dont load i get white page with that loading circle

Comment: What's does swipl-win.exe?

Comment: it execute the prolog code. its a simple code "test:- write('Hello!')." just for test

Comment: Try $output=exec("c:/Program Files (x86)/swipl/bin/swipl-win.exe -f test.pl -g test");

Comment: when i do this, the page load but i dont get the results, i mean the output is empty while its suposed to return me "Hello!".

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you should use the `-f` option. It does something different from what you think it does. Try passing the Prolog source file as the last argument, without any switches, for example:

```
$output=exec("\"c:/Program Files (x86)/swipl/bin/swipl-win.exe\" -g test test.pl");
```

You might also want to actually tell Prolog to immediately halt after doing whatever `test/0` does, for example:

```
$output=exec("\"c:/Program Files (x86)/swipl/bin/swipl-win.exe\" -g test,halt test.pl");
```

I am not sure whether you need to quote `test,halt` in any way on Windows because of the comma or not.

Comment: it doesnt work neither , continuious load without displaying the page and when i type it like this '$output=exec("c:/Program Files (x86)/swipl/bin/swipl-win.exe -g test test.pl");' it gives me an empty output

Comment: A better way to halt is: `-t halt`. This also halts if the goal fails or raises an exception.

Comment: @mat well the "clean" way is `-g test,halt -t halt(1)` or something along these lines I guess.

Comment: @MessiAdrinho If I were you I would first try to run the whole command line you now have inside `exec` to see if this works as expected. Have you done that already? At the very least, you should see that it prints out "Hello!" and exits.

Comment: if u mean inside swiple prolog then yes it works and it prints Hello!, but when i use it with PHP it return me an empty output

Comment: @MessiAdrinho Not inside prolog, but rather run, from the Windows shell, `swipl-win.exe -g "test,halt" -t "halt(1)" test.pl` and see if this prints "Hello!" on the command line and immediately exits.

Comment: @MessiAdrinho Well figure out how to run this first, I skipped the location of `swipl-win.exe` in my example because it will be system dependent.

Comment: it worked this way 'C:\wamp\www\Sudoku>"C:\Program Files (x86)\swipl\bin\swipl-win.exe" -g test test
.pl'